# Android Vulkan linker command failed

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, vulkan

I'm trying to use Vulkan on Android so I had installed android ndk. I saw that in Android Studio default native C++, Vulkan is included. But whenever I build I get the following error:

> C:/Users/a18/AndroidStudioProjects/vulkanSMD/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:34:
>   error: undefined reference to 'vkCreateInstance' clang++: error:
>   linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've tried including `libvulkan.so` and also tried `dlopen("libvulkan.so", flags)` but it is of no use.
I'm trying to get Vulkan working on android. The below code creates a vulkan instance.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#define VK_USE_PLATFORM_ANDROID_KHR 1
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>

std::vector<const char *>extensions;
std::vector<const char *>layers;

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_vulkansmd_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {

    extensions = std::vector<const char *>({
                                                   "VK_EXT_debug_report",
                                                   "VK_KHR_surface",
                                           });
    layers = std::vector<const char *>({"VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation"});
    VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo = {};
    VkApplicationInfo appInfo = {};
    appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    appInfo.pApplicationName = "Vulkan is hard";
    appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_VERSION_1_0;
    appInfo.engineVersion = VK_VERSION_1_0;
    appInfo.apiVersion = VK_VERSION_1_0 ;
    createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    createInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;
    createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensions.data();
    createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(extensions.size());
    createInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = layers.data();
    createInfo.enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(layers.size());
    VkInstance  instance;
    vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instance);

    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

While building however I get the following error

> Build command failed. Error while executing process
>   C:\Users\a18\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe
>   with arguments {--build
>   C:\Users\a18\AndroidStudioProjects\vulkanSMD\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\x86_64
>   --target native-lib} [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o [2/2] Linking CXX shared
>   library
>   C:\Users\a18\AndroidStudioProjects\vulkanSMD\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\x86_64\libnative-lib.so
>   FAILED:
>   C:/Users/a18/AndroidStudioProjects/vulkanSMD/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86_64/libnative-lib.so
>   cmd.exe /C "cd . &&
>   C:\Users\a18\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe
>   --target=x86_64-none-linux-android26 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/a18/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64
>   --sysroot=C:/Users/a18/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot
>   -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-addrsig -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o C:\Users\a18\AndroidStudioProjects\vulkanSMD\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\x86_64\libnative-lib.so
>   CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o  -llog -latomic -lm && cd
>   ."
>   C:/Users/a18/AndroidStudioProjects/vulkanSMD/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:34:
>   error: undefined reference to 'vkCreateInstance' clang++: error:
>   linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Comment: I don't see `libvulkan` in the linker command.  See here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis

Comment: so what do I do ?

Comment: Follow the steps in __Using native APIs__ in the link above